# SQL Server - Implementing sequences

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sequence

I have a system which requires I have IDs on my data before it goes to the database. I was using GUIDs, but found them to be too big to justify the convenience.

I'm now experimenting with implementing a sequence generator which basically reserves a range of unique ID values for a given context. The code is as follows;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sequence.ReserveSequence]
@Name varchar(100),
@Count int,
@FirstValue bigint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Ensure the parameters are valid
IF (@Name IS NULL OR @Count IS NULL OR @Count < 0)
    RETURN -1;

-- Reserve the sequence
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    -- Get the sequence ID, and the last reserved value of the sequence
    DECLARE @SequenceID int;
    DECLARE @LastValue bigint;

    SELECT TOP 1 @SequenceID = [ID], @LastValue = [LastValue]
    FROM [dbo].[Sequences]
    WHERE [Name] = @Name;

    -- Ensure the sequence exists
    IF (@SequenceID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        -- Create the new sequence
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Sequences] ([Name], [LastValue])
        VALUES (@Name, @Count);

        -- The first reserved value of a sequence is 1
        SET @FirstValue = 1;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Update the sequence
        UPDATE [dbo].[Sequences]
        SET [LastValue] = @LastValue + @Count
        WHERE [ID] = @SequenceID;

        -- The sequence start value will be the last previously reserved value + 1
        SET @FirstValue = @LastValue + 1;
    END

COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

The 'Sequences' table is just an ID, Name (unique), and the last allocated value of the sequence. Using this procedure I can request N values in a named sequence and use these as my identifiers.

This works great so far - it's extremely quick since I don't have to constantly ask for individual values, I can just use up a range of values and then request more.

The problem is that at extremely high frequency, calling the procedure concurrently can sometimes result in a deadlock. I have only found this to occur when stress testing, but I'm worried it'll crop up in production. Are there any notable flaws in this procedure, and can anyone recommend any way to improve on it? It would be nice to do with without transactions for example, but I do need this to be 'thread safe'.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea.  Use the inherent `Identity` data type, otherwise you **will** have locking issues you need to handle manually.

Comment: As I said, Identity isn't practical for me as I need the ID /before/ the data goes into the database.

Comment: Why would you need the ID before it goes into the DB?  Your suggested solution is simply pre-allocating the IDs - therefore why not use an identity field, create empty records to create IDs and then update instead of insert?  Any unused records can be deleted.

Comment: @JNK - I never said it was a database issue! I just said it doesn't suit me. :)

Comment: @Martin - The short answer is that this is relational data, and I insert into the database using BULKCOPY. I can't do a round-trip to get the IDs, so I need to know what they are beforehand.

Comment: Wait for SQL Server 2011 "Denali" - it will support native `SEQUENCES` in SQL SErver

Comment: Fairy snuff.  In that case can you not construct an ID from a Batch Id and a simple sequence that can be managed by your bulk insert?  If your batch ID cannot be made unique without a call to the DB then at least it only needs to be fetched once at start of processing.

Comment: @Martin: the OP's request is a valid and very common need in ETL. I used this approach many times myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I'd share my solution. I doesn't deadlock, nor does it produce duplicate values. An important difference between this and my original procedure is that it doesn't create the queue if it doesn't already exist;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReserveSequence]
(
    @Name nvarchar(100),
    @Count int,
    @FirstValue bigint OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@Count <= 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @FirstValue = NULL;
        RETURN -1;
    END

    DECLARE @Result TABLE ([LastValue] bigint)

    -- Update the sequence last value, and get the previous one 
    UPDATE [Sequences]
    SET [LastValue] = [LastValue] + @Count
    OUTPUT INSERTED.LastValue INTO @Result
    WHERE [Name] = @Name;

    -- Select the first value
    SELECT TOP 1 @FirstValue = [LastValue] + 1 FROM @Result;
END
```

Answer (score 4):

MS [themselves offer a solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx) and even they say it locks/deadlocks. 
If you want to add some lock hints then you'd reduce concurrency for your high loads

Options:

- You could develop against the "Denali" CTP which is the next release
- Use IDENTITY and the OUTPUT clause like everyone else
- Adopt/modify the solutions above

On DBA.SE there is ["Emulate a TSQL sequence via a stored procedure"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/3307/630): see dportas' answer which I think extends the MS solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend sticking with the GUIDs, if as you say, this is mostly about composing data ready for a bulk insert (it's simpler than what I present below).

As an alternative, could you work with a restricted count? Say, 100 ID values at a time? In that case, you could have a table with an IDENTITY column, insert into that table, return the generated ID (say, 39), and then your code could assign all values between 3900 and 3999 (e.g. multiply up by your assumed granularity) without consulting the database server again.

Of course, this could be extended to allocating multiple IDs in a single call - provided that your okay with some IDs potentially going unused. E.g. you need 638 IDs - so you ask the database to assign you 7 new ID values (which imply that you've allocated 700 values), use the 638 you want, and the remaining 62 never get assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get some kind of deadlock trace?  For example, [enable trace flag 1222 as shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx).  Duplicate the deadlock.  Then look in the SQL Server log for the deadlock trace.

Also, you might inspect what locks are taken out in your code by inserting a call to exec [sp_lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187749.aspx) or select * from [sys.dm_tran_locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx) immediately before the `COMMIT TRANSACTION`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are observing a conversion deadlock. To avoid them, you want to make sure that your table is clustered and has a PK, but this advice is specific to 2005 and 2008 R2, and they can change the implementation, rendering this advice useless. Google up "Some heap tables may be more prone to deadlocks than identical tables with clustered indexes".

Anyway, if you observe an error during stress testing, it is likely that sooner or later it will occur in production as well.

You may want to use sp_getapplock to serialize your requests. Google up "Application Locks (or Mutexes) in SQL Server 2005". Also I described a few useful ideas here: "Developing Modifications that Survive Concurrency".