# How to create sequence in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sequence

I am creating sequence in SQL Server with the following code. But it displays error as unknown object type. Please give a solution

Here's my code :

```
create sequence seqval start with 100 increment by 1 minvalue 0 maxvalue 0 no cycle  
 no cache;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK there is no `SEQUENCE` syntax in sql server 2008 .It is available only in `2012`

Comment: then can u plz let me know how to create auto generated key in sql2008???

Comment: Sequences are new in SQL Server **2012** and not available in earlier versions. Use `CREATE TABLE YourTable (ID INT IDENTITY)` - the mechanism in SQL Server 2008 is `IDENTITY`. [Read about `IDENTITY` on MSDN SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Implementing sequences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750614/sql-server-implementing-sequences)

Comment: Refer https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number/ and https://gist.github.com/Jumpercables/7601830

Answer (score 9):

You can do this.

```
--Create a dummy TABLE to generate a SEQUENCE. No actual records will be stored.
CREATE TABLE SequenceTABLE
(
    ID BIGINT IDENTITY  
);
GO

--This procedure is for convenience in retrieving a sequence.
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetSEQUENCE ( @value BIGINT OUTPUT)
AS
    --Act like we are INSERTing a row to increment the IDENTITY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT SequenceTABLE WITH (TABLOCKX) DEFAULT VALUES;
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    --Return the latest IDENTITY value.
    SELECT @value = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
GO

--Example execution
DECLARE @value BIGINT;
EXECUTE dbo.GetSEQUENCE @value OUTPUT;
SELECT @value AS [@value];
GO
```

Comment: If using this inside a TRANSACTION, you will need to change the procedure to remove the TRANSACTION and DELETE the row you INSERTed, or you need to use a Job to periodically clean up the table, as needed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use SELECT @value = IDENT_CURRENT('SequenceTABLE'); instead of SCOPE_IDENTITY(); to ensure the table you are getting the identity from is the one you want to?

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Numbers` table; here's a [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table) question on the subject.  Let's call it `dbo.Number`.

Have a table with an identity column. Set the seed and step to whatever is appropriate:

```
create table dbo.SequenceGenerator(ID int identity(1, 1), dummy int);
```

Then insert values from the numbers table and capture the newly-generated identity values:

```
declare @HowMany int = 3;  -- This determines how large a sequence you receive
                           -- at each itteration
declare @NewSequenceValue table (ID int);

insert dbo.SequenceGenerator(dummy)
output INSERTED.ID 
    into @NewSequenceValue
select Number from dbo.Numbers
where Number <= @HowMany;

select * from @NewSequenceValue;
```

Be sure to `DELETE .. dbo.SequenceGenerator` from time to time, else it will get big for no additional value.  Do not `TRUNCATE` it - that will reset the `IDENTITY` column to its initally-declared seed value.

Comment: yes I agree. I found this blog entry http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askjay/archive/2012/10/08/sequence-objects-in-sql-2012-and-sql-2008.aspx, which describes the same solution nicely, and compares it with SQL 2012's capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 can't create sequences, Sequence objects apply to SQL Server 2012 through current versions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ff878091(v=sql.120).aspx

You can use an IDENTITY in your table instead, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

The starting value for IDENTITY is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: While a valid answer it's a little out of context. The OP did not state the sequence was intended for a tables key, it may be required and often is for  use case other than a key.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH N0 as (SELECT 1 as n UNION ALL SELECT 1)
,N1 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N0 t1, N0 t2)
,N2 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N1 t1, N1 t2)
,N3 as (SELECT 1 as n FROM N2 t1, N2 t2)
,nums as (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as num FROM N3)
SELECT * FROM nums
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't use Sequence easily in SQL Server 2008.

You can use CTE(Common Table Expressions) for Sequence Generation in SQL Server 2008

```sql
WITH NUM_GEN (n) AS
     ( 
            SELECT 1 
            UNION 
                  ALLSELECT n+1 
            FROM  NUM_GEN 
            WHERE n+1< MAX_VALUE 
     ) 
SELECT n 
FROM   NUM_GEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following article:
https://www.learnjavaupdate.com/2023/04/sequence-in-sql.html

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE company_seq
   START WITH 100
   INCREMENT BY 1
   MAXVALUE 999
   NOCACHE
   NOCYCLE;
```

The above script creates a sequence called `company_seq` that starts at 100 and increments by 1 for each subsequent call to the `NEXTVAL` function. The sequence has a maximum value of 999, meaning that once the sequence reaches 999, it will stop generating values. The `NOCACHE` option specifies that Oracle should not cache sequence values, and the `NOCYCLE` option specifies that the sequence should not cycle back to its starting value when it reaches its maximum value.

Once the sequence is created, you can use the `NEXTVAL` function to generate unique values:

```
INSERT INTO companies (company_id, company_name)

VALUES (company_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Dummy');
```

Comment: “…specifies that Oracle should…” The question clearly indicates that the OP is using SQL Server 2008. Are you sure this will work in SQL Server?

Answer (score -3):

Are you sure you're running 2012? I had no trouble with:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seqval
START WITH 100
INCREMENT BY 1 
minvalue 100 maxvalue 10000 NO CYCLE
```

Your 0,0 values generated a syntax error for me but a clear and simple one.

```
The minimum value for sequence object 'seqval' must be less than its maximum value.
```